# Update a column with the value from previous row based on Previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has Inside_churn based on the result I need to update row after that.
Source table looks like this:

```
 soli               snapshotdate         Madchangeflag  Within15days crdpushpullflag Inside_Churn
302341-210        2018-08-13 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PO             0
302341-210        2018-08-14 00:00:00.000   Y                  N         PI             0
302341-210        2018-08-15 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PI             1
302341-210        2018-08-16 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PO             0
302341-210        2018-08-17 00:00:00.000   Y                  N         PI             0
302341-210        2018-08-18 00:00:00.000   N                  N         PI             0
302341-210        2018-08-19 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PI             1
302341-210        2018-08-20 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PO             0
602341-110        2018-08-13 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PO             0
602341-110        2018-08-14 00:00:00.000   Y                  N         PI             0
602341-110        2018-08-15 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PI             1
602341-110        2018-08-16 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PO             0
602341-110        2018-08-17 00:00:00.000   Y                  N         PI             0
602341-110        2018-08-18 00:00:00.000   N                  N         PI             0
602341-110        2018-08-19 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PI             1
602341-110        2018-08-20 00:00:00.000   Y                  Y         PO             0
```

If any ID has latest date record as Inside_Churn =1 then following records which has Madchangeflag ='Y' and crdpushpullflag='PI' should be updated as Inside_Churn =1

ouput expected:

```
soli        snapshotdate            Madchangeflag   Within15days crdpushpullflag   Inside_Churn
302341-210  2018-08-13 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PO           0
302341-210  2018-08-14 00:00:00.000        Y              N               PI           0
302341-210  2018-08-15 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PI           1
302341-210  2018-08-16 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PO           0
302341-210  2018-08-17 00:00:00.000        Y              N               PI           1
302341-210  2018-08-18 00:00:00.000        N              N               PI           0
302341-210  2018-08-19 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PI           1
302341-210  2018-08-20 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PO           0
602341-110  2018-08-13 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PO           0
602341-110  2018-08-14 00:00:00.000        Y              N               PI           0
602341-110  2018-08-15 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PI           1
602341-110  2018-08-16 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PO           0
602341-110  2018-08-17 00:00:00.000        Y              N               PI           1
602341-110  2018-08-18 00:00:00.000        N              N               PI           0
602341-110  2018-08-19 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PI           1
602341-110  2018-08-20 00:00:00.000        Y              Y               PO           0
```

Comment: I dont understand your condition `If any ID has latest date record as Inside_Churn =1`. The row you changed for 302341-210 is not the latest row for this key. Why did you pick that one and not the lastrow for the key?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong description its not latest( was trying to say record that comes first) we need to consider oldest in terms of date.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will show the result you are after. Still not convinced I've understood the question, but it will turn your before data into your required data so hopefully covers it.

First part is to create the test table:

```
declare @t table(soli varchar(20), snapshotdate date, Madchangeflag char(1),  Within15days char(1), crdpushpullflag char(2), Inside_Churn int)
insert @t values ('302341-210','2018-08-13','Y','Y','PO',0)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-14','Y','N','PI',0)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-15','Y','Y','PI',1)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-16','Y','Y','PO',0)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-17','Y','N','PI',0)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-18','N','N','PI',0)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-19','Y','Y','PI',1)
, ('302341-210','2018-08-20','Y','Y','PO',0)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-13','Y','Y','PO',0)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-14','Y','N','PI',0)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-15','Y','Y','PI',1)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-16','Y','Y','PO',0)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-17','Y','N','PI',0)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-18','N','N','PI',0)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-19','Y','Y','PI',1)
, ('602341-110','2018-08-20','Y','Y','PO',0)
```

Then to do the update and show results:

```
update t set inside_churn=1
from @t t
where t.Madchangeflag='y' and t.crdpushpullflag='PI' and t.Inside_Churn=0
-- Make sure this is the last target row
and not exists(
    select * from @t t2 
    where t2.soli=t.soli 
    and t2.Madchangeflag='y' and t2.crdpushpullflag='PI' and t2.Inside_Churn=0 
    and t2.snapshotdate>t.snapshotdate
    )
-- Make sure there is a later row with inside_churn=1
and exists(
    select * from @t t3 
    where t3.soli=t.soli 
    and t3.Madchangeflag='y' and t3.crdpushpullflag='PI' and t3.Inside_Churn=1 
    and t3.snapshotdate>t.snapshotdate
    )

select * from @t
```